# swagger-ui and a dynamic hostname

Tags: json, https, swagger-ui

I have a server that I generate dynamically from a template, and it exposes an API rooted at `/api`. I only access it with HTTPS. If I specify the `baseUrl` as "/api", swagger-ui tries to access `/api` but with HTTP (and my browser says "locked loading mixed active content").

If I give `https://hostname/api` as the `basePath` things work fine, but I don't want the JSON file to be different for each server.

Any ideas?

Thanks, Yaron

Answer (score 1):

Even if the OP have already found the answer, others may not, so I'll try to answer. You should specify `schemes` property (Swagger 2.0):

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "schemes": [ "https" ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just leave the `schemes` property blank, swagger-ui will use the same scheme used to access the `swagger.json` file.

From [the docs](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#fixed-fields):

> If the schemes is not included, the default scheme to be used is the
>   one used to access the Swagger definition itself.